# Connection failure you must change db settings talend 7.3.1

Tags: jdbc, mariadb, connection, talend

I tried to create in metadata db connections to MySQL (MariaDB ) to a distant server and the check failed with the error:Connection failure. You must change the Database Settings.

```
Echec de la connexion Vous devez modifier les paramètres de la base de données.

 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not connect to : unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)
   at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:208)
   at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataUtils.connect(ExtractMetaDataUtils.java:1146)
   at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.testConnection(ExtractMetaDataFromDataBase.java:315)
   at org.talend.metadata.managment.repository.ManagerConnection.check(ManagerConnection.java:290)
   at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm$67.runWithCancel(DatabaseForm.java:4208)
   at org.talend.repository.ui.wizards.metadata.connection.database.DatabaseForm$67.runWithCancel(DatabaseForm.java:1)
   at org.talend.repository.ui.dialog.AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel$1.runnableWithCancel(AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel.java:77)
   at org.talend.repository.ui.dialog.AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel$ARunnableWithProgressCancel$1.call(AProgressMonitorDialogWithCancel.java:161)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:241)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1241)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.Utils.retrieveProxy(Utils.java:610)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbConnection.newConnection(MariaDbConnection.java:142)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:86)
   at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.DriverShim.connect(DriverShim.java:41)
   at org.talend.core.model.metadata.builder.database.JDBCDriverLoader.getConnection(JDBCDriverLoader.java:199)
   ... 9 more
 Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.get(ExceptionMapper.java:241)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.util.exceptions.ExceptionMapper.connException(ExceptionMapper.java:87)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:524)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.connectWithoutProxy(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:1236)
   ... 14 more
 Caused by: java.io.EOFException: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4 (socket was closed by server)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacketArray(StandardPacketInputStream.java:243)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.io.input.StandardPacketInputStream.getPacket(StandardPacketInputStream.java:212)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.com.read.ReadInitialHandShakePacket.<init>(ReadInitialHandShakePacket.java:90)
   at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.protocol.AbstractConnectProtocol.createConnection(AbstractConnectProtocol.java:480)
   ... 15 more
```

Do you have any ideas how to solve the problem?

[image: Connection settings]

Comment: Databases are usually not reachable over the internet, you use a ssh tunnel for exampöle to connect, but as you don't which to give away credentials, you need to write the request as REST api

Answer (score 0):

I usually follow these steps if SQL connection throws error:-
Wherever you are running your talend (local pc or remote server),
**first check connecting to SQL with same credentials in sql db application**.

Like I am using Oracle SQL so I tested my connection in Oracle SQL Developer application first. I check minor details like (using Service or ID option).

**Either DB is down, or the server doesn't have access to DB
(in these cases I won't be able to connect in my DB application too)**

**or
Something must be missing in my tDBConnection settings**, I usually make the "Service" setting mistake.
Sync it with SQL Dev settings and then it works.
(Don't know about MariaDB but I guess mistake would be same, in login settings)